# Numbers as sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

As you can see in the questions in my profile I am struggling with mathematical notation. Now my objective is to define numbers and I find out that can be defined as sets:

$$0=\varnothing,1=\{\varnothing\},2=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\cdots $$
$$0=\{\},1=\{0\},2=\{0,1\}\cdots $$

This definition was gave by von Neumann to define ordinal numbers. My question is, can these numbers be used as normal? For example:
$$\mathbb{N}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\cdots\}$$
Is this possible? Because we would be saying that $\mathbb{N}$ is another ordinal, not a set of numbers.
$$1+2=\{\varnothing\}+\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}=\{\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}=3$$

I don't know if this is equalities make sense (probably not) but I want to know if there's a way to formalize numbers to give them a formal definition

**NEW QUESTION**

If we take this definition of 1 does this work?
$$A=\{x,y,z\}$$
$$A\cup\{0\}=A\cup1=\{x,y,z,0\}=\{x,y,z,\varnothing\}$$
It looks weird but should be right. Am I wrong?

Comment: They can be used as *normal*. However, to do so, you need to also define the *normal operations*, like addition, multiplication, exponentiation… which can indeed be done for ordinals.

Comment: So, if they can be used as normal, is  the natural set an infinite number?? Is the infinite number of infinite natural numbers combinations, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite more numbers than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: See also Zermelo's ordinals. Even simpler.

Comment: It all depends on what you name a number! But for sure, $\mathbb N$ can be identified to an ordinal, usually named $\omega$. Regarding $\mathbb R$, despite not being an ordinal (as for example it doesn’t have a least element) can be defined in the set theory.

Comment: Please, ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

We can build mathematics based on these von Neumann ordinals, but we have to do some ground work first, like Peano did to axiomatize arithmetic:

- For a finite ordinals $a$ and $b$, we define $a+0\stackrel{def}{=}a$, and $a+(b\cup\{b\})\stackrel{def}{=}(a+b)\cup\{a+b\}$. This definition of addition is complete by induction on the right-hand argument. For example, $3+1=(3+0)\cup\{3+0\}=3\cup\{3\}$, which we call $4$.
- Similarly, we define $a\times 0\stackrel{def}{=}0$ and $a\times(b\cup\{b\})\stackrel{def}{=}a+(a\times b)$. This time, the induction is also done on the right-hand argument, but the inductive step assumes $+$ has already been defined for all $b$, or at least all $b\leq a\times b$.

These definitions are clunkier than the intuitive operations on sets like taking unions (as far as I know this clunkiness of von Neumann ordinals is a popular argument for using simpler type-theory-based definitions as a foundation for arithmetic.) However as pointed out in the main comments, they're necessary, as taking unions fails to perform addition. (In fact, $a\cup b$ for two ordinal numbers is only $\textrm{max}(a,b)$, since each ordinal number is the set of ordinals less than itself.)